Can the bilingual keyboard functionality in iOS 18 be completely disabled?
I just upgraded to iOS 18 on my phone, which brought with it the very unwelcome change that most of my keyboard layouts are now ‘bilingual’. I do not ever want any of my keyboard layouts to be bilingual, since it is absolutely terrible at identifying what language you write when – like me – you often write things in multiple languages. Autocorrect has become almost entirely unusable with this change.
I have more than 20 keyboard layouts (yes, I realise this is unusual, but I really do type in most of them on a regular basis), and about 15 of them are now ‘bilingual’. Unfortunately, while I can easily delete the non-English language from a bilingual keyboard, it seems you cannot remove English to make it a single-language non-English keyboard layout. Instead, I have to now remove 15 layouts, re-add them one at a time, actively choose the single-language option (since bilingual is now the default), then reorder them the way I want them. And remember to choose the single-language option every time I want to add a new layout.
This to me is absolutely atrocious UI, so I’ve been trying to find some setting or method to completely disable the bilingual feature so that all keyboards (existing and future) are forced to single-language mode… but so far no dice.
Is it possible to disable the bilingual keyboard functionality system-wide in iOS 18?
